# J2ME UI on Samsung Bada platform

Tags: user-interface, java-me, midp, bada, lcdui

When a J2ME application runs on Samsung phone with  <strike>Samsung Bada</strike> an OS that supports TouchWhiz (GT-S5320, in my case),a virtual keypad is shown on the screen by default and always! This virtual keypad consists of the following keys - LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN,FIRE and SOFT1, SOFT2.

Is there anyway I can control when this keypad is displayed and when it isn't. I understand that this would be a platform specific solution. But does it exist?
Thanks,
-- Kiran Kuppa

EDIT: I must also note that Google Maps, ( seems to be a J2ME app) does not show this keypad. I am sure there must be a way to supress it.

EDIT2: Thanks for the correction. I am attaching a picture to illustrate.[image]

Comment: This phone S5320 does not runs bada platform, please change your question. wave s8500 the only phone runs bada as of now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

MIDlet-Touch-Support: True

in the jad/manifest to remove the on-screen pad.

Just for more information, if your handset supports rotation with an accelerometer this too can be controlled with a jad parameter:

MIDlet-ScreenMode: Rotate       //to allow rotation
MIDlet-ScreenMode: Portrait     //to force to portrait
MIDlet-ScreenMode: Landscape    //to force to landscape

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This piece of information and some additional important stuff is available in Knowledge base of Samsung Mobile Innovator portal as an article entitled " Samsung Native Text Input".

Answer (score 0):

The virtual keyboard appears for j2me application if it not uses TouchUI functionality

Comment: Suresh, thanks for the correction. I guess the UI is called TouchWhiz- it looks much like Samsung Corby. Anyways, can I turn this virtual keypad by any means? I must note that even if my MIDlet uses just the pointer events, I can see this keypad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

on bada 1.2 (not on bada 1.0 and not on bada 2.0, *grr*) there was an option in the "games and more" (=java) menu, where you could manually enable or disable the 1) keypad and 2) the way the app is shown, stretched to display (but 240x320) or not-stretched(and full 480x800).